# how to gather the results from a nested for loop in C++ and MPI

Tags: c++, for-loop, mpi

Here there is a matrix (mm, 10 samples* 1000 features), I want to get the own-defined distance between 10 samples. In other words, there are 10+...+4+3+2+1 calculations (I need the distance between one sample, too).

the serial C++ code like this:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
    for (j=0; j<10; j++){
        disX <- dis(mm[i], mm[j])    
    }
}
```

how can I use MPI_GATHER the collect the disX? Could you give me an example script similar this? I just google (MPI nested for loop c++), but got bad searching results. The real mm matrix is big and the memory for dis function is small. Thank you.

Comment: The recent answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/28759593/491687) sounds very similar to your problem. It sounds like you shouldn't be using MPI at all, but perhaps OpenMP.

Comment: @WesleyBland I need multi nodes to calculate as the computation is really large.

Comment: @WesleyBland the complex of this problem, different the one you cited, lies in the nested for loop.